# Spectrum of a continuous function on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a banach algebra with identity $e$. If $x\in A$ the spectrum, $\sigma(x)$ is defined to be the set of all complex numbers $\lambda$ so that $x-\lambda e$ is not invertible.

In the case where $A=C(K)$, that is the space of all complex valued continuous functions on a compact set $K$ with the sup norm. The spectrum of $f\in A$, $\sigma(f)$ is the image of $f$. Why is this true?

One direction seems relatively straightforward. If $\lambda\in \textrm{im} f$ then there exists a $x\in K$ so that $\lambda = f(x)$.  Let $y\in K$ and suppose $(f-\lambda e)(x)=(f-\lambda e)(y)$. It then follows that $0=f(y)-\lambda$ or $f(y)=\lambda$. So $f$ must be constant (for it to be injective). However if f is identically $\lambda$ then $f-\lambda e=0$, which is not invertible.

The other direction is giving me trouble. If $\lambda\in \sigma(f)$ then $f-\lambda e$ is not invertible. This means that either $f-\lambda e$ is not injective or it is not surjective (if it was bijective, then it would have continuous inverse since $K$ is compact).

Comment: The question is which functions $K \to \mathbb{C}$ are invertible with respect to *pointwise multiplication* (the answer is precisely the functions which are nowhere zero), which has nothing to do with which functions are invertible with respect to *composition*, so injectivity and surjectivity have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confused about what being invertible means in $C(K)$. It has a ring structure where multiplication is pointwise multiplication, and invertible means having a multiplicative inverse.  If the inverse of $f$ exists in this sense, it is $1/f$.  In order for $1/f$ to exist, $f$ has to be nonzero everywhere.  The function $e$ is equal to $1$ everywhere.

If $\lambda$ is in the image of $f$, then $0$ is in the image of $f-\lambda e$, so $1/(f-\lambda e)$ doesn't exist.

If $f-\lambda e$ isn't invertible, then $1/(f-\lambda e)$ doesn't exist, so $f-\lambda e$ must be $0$ somewhere, so $\lambda$ must be in the image of $f$.